# creating an echo timestamp / cannot use pipe in echo string

Tags: shell, unix, unix-timestamp

I would like to use timestamps for logging outputs in a scriptfile.

On the console

**date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_%N**

prints something like **"20120206_104531_944652200"**

In order to cut all those nano and mikro seconds I found

**date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_%N | sed s,".\{6\}$",,**

which gives me something like **"20120206_104531_944"**

In a scriptfile it seems to be somewhat different.
The timestamp must be *evaluated each time* a logging output is done.

This scriptcode works:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
log_prefix1="date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_%N"

echo "`${log_prefix1}` blabla"
sleep 3
echo "`${log_prefix1}` blabla"
```

Unfortunately I did not find a way to get this running with only the 3 most significant digits of the nanoseconds.

This scriptcode does not work:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
log_prefix="date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_%N | sed s,\".\{6\}$\",,"

echo "`${log_prefix}` blabla"
sleep 3
echo "`${log_prefix}` blabla"
```

I get the following error message:

```
date: extra operand `|'
Try `date --help' for more information.
```

So, something is going wrong with the pipe to sed at execution time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can make your life a bit simpler by creating a function for that.

Something like:

```
log_echo() { 
  echo $(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_%N | sed 's,.\{6\}$,,') "$@";
}

...

log_echo hello there
```

Comment: `$*` is not DWIM-compliant; for example try strings with multiple consecutive whitespace characters. Use `"$@"` instead.